# buildcraft combustion engines overheat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-buildcraft

I have an issue with combustion engines. As seen in the pictures below, I have a test setup with 2 combustion engines. I am using gold fluid pipes for the water pumping. When the combustion engines reach about 100 degrees, the water drops to zero and after that, the heat of the engines increases. 
Anyone knows what the issue might be?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your problem is that water disappears when it reaches 100°C? I don't know the mod, but in reality this would mean that it's now gas.

Comment: Lol in reality it would, yea

Answer (score 1):

I think  you need to be activley pumping in more water than fuel to compensate on these engines, the gold wont affect that as its not an increase in vulume, try having a second pump systems adding to the water intake, two pipes in on each combustion engine, that might compensate enough.

Then again combustion engines are notorious for being utterly useless due to constant overheating and exploding, I prefer solar